# how to backup os of server using xcopy

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, xcopy

I have been able to backup some files with the xcopy command using the following code in my batch file.

```
  xcopy  /e /s /d /i /y  "C:\Users\ba\Desktop\all\a" "C:\Users\ba\Desktop\all\bb" >> "C:\Users\bar\Desktop\log.txt"
```

Is there a way to use xcopy to backup server os please?

Comment: Janet - From one far away planet, it's [URBackup](https://www.urbackup.org/) to the rescue in some cases

Answer (score 0):

Not with *xcopy*, because "OS files" are a little different from "ordinary files".

The Operating System has control files, configuration files, status files, and more, and these files are not accessed by user.

Another thing is: during installation, the operating system change the hard disk boot record, and a "simple copy" will not copy the boot record.

You need to copy the "installations files" of your operating system, and in allmost cases this means: make an image of Install CD.

Answer (score 0):

No. Windows Server 2008 R2 is so complex that it cannot be backed up using `xcopy`. Its open files stop `xcopy` and the bootloader, installed into a separate hidden partition cannot be backed up by `xcopy`.

You need to use Windows Server Backup, a component of Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: am trying to use the windows server backup - when i select the drive which has the OS to back up i get "unsupported file system and cant back up"...Please what am i missing? any way out?

Comment: Yes. Something is definitely wrong, although I can't say what from here. You need to have a local admin look at it.